# using spacewalk repository for patching ubuntu servers

Tags: repository

I'm trying to set up spacewalk 2.10 repos for patching our ubuntu 16, 18 and 20 servers.

I was able to configure and connect successfully with 16, it has all the rhel packages in the ubuntu 16 mirrors.  But when I run apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories it only sees a few of my repos, ignores the rest. I had to build the spacewalk debs from source that I pulled from a 16 server for 18 and 20 OS, but can successfully register both 18 and 20 after
building the debs and installing them. But when I try to run update all my 18 and 20 repos return as ignored and I get

Failed to fetch spacewalk://myspacewalkserver/dists/channels:/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found.

update returns this for 16:

Get:8 spacewalk://myspacewalkserver channels:/main amd64 Packages [1,306 kB]

this for 18 and 20:

Ign:3 spacewalk://myspacewalkserver channels:/main amd64 Packages

I'm syncing identical channels for each OS, just changed xenial for bionic and focal:

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/

and I have packages in my spacewalk repos for all 3 OS's.

Any idea what I can troubleshoot in either my servers or in spacewalk to get these working?

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 16, 18 & 20.  Ubuntu releases that use *yy* format (such as Ubuntu Core 16 .. 20) cannot use local repositories, as they only use *snaps* from the Canonical Snapstore.  Ubuntu has both *yy.mm* and *yy* releases, but are different products. The repositories you specifically mention are for *yy.mm* baed releases and **not** *yy* based releases such as Ubuntu Core 16 etc.  It may help if you correct or clarify your question.

Comment: to clarify, they are 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04 releases